# Commands works in CLI but 1 doesn't in a script

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following in my script, and `directory2` contains those 4 jar files

```
cd /home/directory1
ln -s /home/directory2/test1.jar .
ln -s /home/directory2/test2.jar .
ln -s /home/directory2/test3.jar .
ln -s /home/directory2/test4.jar .
```

The first 3 are executed properly however the last one fails with the error

`ln: failed to access ‘–s’: No such file or directory`

Also, all 4 works in CLI. What might cause the last one to produce that error?

Comment: Use 4 spaces to indent blocks. Back-tick is for in-line indentation only.

Comment: The code you posted uses the correct ASCII hyphen-minus character for each `ln -s`; the error message you posted indicates your code is using the Unicode en dash.

Comment: What editor did you use to create the script?  Some word processors may try to guess for you when you want an en-dash in a document instead of a plain dash.  You are likely better off using a programmer's editor.

Comment: The editor I used was Notepad++, both dashes look the same in the editor.

Comment: I see that others have had the look-similar problem: [How to distinguish en-dash from hyphen in Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563809/how-to-distinguish-en-dash-from-hyphen-in-notepad).  I don't use Notepad myself so I have no suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern computers use unicode which has many characters that look like `-` but aren't.  Make sure that you are using the plain ASCII `-` minus character for `-s`.

Comment: Specifically, the character appearing in the error message is U+2013, an en dash.